# Configure nginx and luameter not working

Tags: nginx, lua

I am just beginner.I am trying to configure nginx and luameter for monitoring nginx.

Here are the step I follow :

1). [Compile openresty](https://openresty.org/)

2). And configure luameter and nginx using this guide :  luameter

I put this code to my nginx configuration :

```
http {
...

lua_shared_dict luameter 1m;
lua_package_path "{CHANGE_ME}?.luac";
init_by_lua "luameter = require 'luameter'";
log_by_lua "luameter.mark_by_host(); luameter.mark_by_path(1)";

...
}    



server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:8001;

    location / {
        root /opt/luameter;
    }

    location /stats {
        content_by_lua "luameter.get_stats('/stats');";
        expires -1;
    }
}
```

I change `{CHANGE_ME}` to `/opt/luameter`but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the process of setting this up too, and according to some examples I found the text `{CHANGE_ME}?` should be replaced with `/opt/luameter/luac/luameter`. So the `lua_package_path` line becomes:

```
lua_package_path "/opt/luameter/luac/luameter.luac";
```